# Having trouble JOINing 3 MySQL tables, retrieving data from two (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database that has a structure like so (simplified for clarity):

### user

- id
- name

### task

- id
- name
- group

### task_link

- user
- task

The query I'm attempting is, basically: **"Get all tasks that are part of this group, along with all users that are assigned to that task"**.

I've used JOIN queries in a few places on this project, but my understanding of them is basic, this unfortunately is a different scenario to the others. My attempt at a JOIN query seems to *almost* work, it looks like (CI Database class formatting, but hopefully it's clear what's happening regardless):

```
$this->db->select('task.name AS taskname, user.name AS username');
$this->db->from('task');
$this->db->from('task_link');
$this->db->where('task.group', $group);
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id = task_link.user');
```

Edit: Dumped as a proper query for clarity:

```
SELECT `user`.`name` AS username, `task`.`name` AS taskname FROM (`task`, `task_link`) JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id` = `task_link`.`user` WHERE `task`.`group` = '7'"
```

I've tried the above with almost every combination of task, task_link and user and end up with the same results each time. Main problems being:

- I get duplicate results, and an odd number of them - I can't quite work out what the grouping is. I seem to be getting 6 results for each task, which is currently the number of 'links'.
- The way that users are 'attached' to the task isn't right; I need the users returned as an array as part of the task (as each task may have multiple users linked to it); whereas I only seem to end up with one user in the result, and multiple results (but not a task for each user).

If it helps understand my model, the view would look something like:

```
foreach($tasks as $task){
  echo $task->taskname;
  foreach($task->username as $user){
    echo $user;
  }
}
```

I know that there are different JOIN clauses, and perhaps more relevant, grouping commands - but my brain is starting to hurt and I think I'm up against the edge of my mysql skills.

Is anyone able to lend a hand getting the above query to work as described? Please just let me know if I've omitted something useful!

Comment: I suggest dumping your query with $this->db->last_query() so you can see the SQL that's created - that may be helpful in figuring out the issue

Comment: Ah, handy command, here you go:

SELECT `user`.`name` AS username, `task`.`name` AS taskname FROM (`task`, `task_link`) JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id` = `task_link`.`user` WHERE `task`.`group` = '7'"

Comment: You might want to put that in the post text rather than as a comment so it's a bit easier to read

Comment: It does not look like, from that SQL, there is any JOIN criteria defined for task and task_link

Comment: @SamA Sorry could you clarify? It's likely something obvious but I've fiddled with this so much it's lost all meaning.

Comment: SamA beat me to it, but that answer looks about right to me. I noticed that there were two FROM statements, and you needed two JOIN statements

Comment: @NathanHornby Basically, you need to select from the task table, then join the user and task_link tables onto it, so you need a separate JOIN statement for each table you join to. Joins can be a bit mind-knotting at times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing on how task_link and task are related but I think the basic SQL you want is:

```
SELECT user.name AS username, task.name AS taskname
FROM task
INNER JOIN task_link ON task.id = task_link.task
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = task_link.user
WHERE task.group = '7'"
```

Which I think translates to this:

```
$this->db->select('task.name AS taskname, user.name AS username');
$this->db->from('task');
$this->db->where('task.group', $group);
$this->db->join('task_link', 'task.id = task_link.task');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id = task_link.user');
```

Comment: That looks like it's heading in a better direction, however I'm getting the following error:


Error Number: 1054


Unknown column 'task_link.user' in 'on clause'

Comment: The tables as defined above mention the task_link table having a "user" column. That error would seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately not. That column definitely exists.

Comment: How about running the SQL and forgetting about the database abstraction code? Either way, I think the JOIN statements were in the wrong order.

Comment: So sorry, that error appears to be because I had the JOIN clauses the wrong way round…

Comment: No, I think that was me. :)

Comment: So this seems to work better than what I had, however where there are two users assigned to a task, I get two 'tasks' back (the same task result, with a different user in each).

Is there a clean way to combine these using MYSQL or is this something I should deal with in the controller/view?

Comment: If all that is required is a unique list of tasks then the SQL statement would change. Without changing it, the results will contain what amounts to a "random" user.

Comment: What I'm seeing when dumping the result is:

`Task1 - Name1`,
`Task1 - Name2`

Whereas ideally what I want is:

`Task1 - [Name1, Name2]`

Does that clarify?

Comment: That has to be done in code when looping over the result set.

Comment: Ok I suspected as much - in which case thanks for the help! I'll mark this as the correct answer.